# Cash Register with Dollars and Quarters output in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I have to program a cash register that has a user input the amount to be paid and it has to output the amount to be paid and then output the number of loonies required to pay the amount followed by the number of quarters required to pay the amount, etc... I've managed to out the amount to be paid as well as the number of loonies required by truncating the amount to be paid, but I'm at a loss as to how to solve the number of quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies required to pay. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)

{
        double cost;
        int loonies, quarters;
        float loonreq;


        printf ("Please enter the amount to be paid: ");
        scanf ("%lf", &cost);

        printf ("Change Due: $ %.2f\n", cost);

        loonies = cost;
        printf ("Loonies required: %d, ", loonies);

        loonreq = cost - loonies;
        printf ("balance owing: $ %.2f\n", loonreq);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you do it on paper? Have you worked that out?

Comment: I tried working it out on paper like you mentioned and then followed up by applying my solution to my code, but my answer is off by .01. The code I applied was:

 quarters = 25;
        quartreq = (loonreq*quarters)/100;
        printf ("balance owing: $ %.2f\n", quartreq);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)

{
    double cost;
    int loonies, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    float loonreq;
    float balance;


    printf ("Please enter the amount to be paid: ");
    scanf ("%lf", &cost);

    printf ("Change Due: $ %.2f\n", cost);

    loonies = cost;
    printf ("Loonies required: %d, ", loonies);

    loonreq = cost - loonies;
    printf ("balance owing: $ %.2f\n", loonreq);

    quarters = (int)(((int)(100*loonreq))/25);
    printf("num quarters: %d \n",quarters);
    balance = loonreq - (quarters*.25);
    printf("balance owing: %.2f$ \n", balance);
    dimes = (int)(((int)(100*balance))/10);
    balance = balance - (dimes*.1);
    printf("num dimes: %d \n", dimes);
    printf("balance owing: %.2f$ \n", balance);

    nickels = (int)(((int)(100*balance))/5);
    printf("num nickels: %d \n", nickels);
    balance = balance - (nickels*.05);
    pennies = (int)(balance*100);
    printf("balance owing: %.2f$ \n", balance);
    printf("num pennies: %d \n", pennies);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've been trying to figure out the equation to use to output the correct value, but the closest I kept getting was off by .01.

Comment: I did, although it doesn't display publicly because my reputation is not above 15 yet. Also, is the int necessary such as for quarters? I removed the int and only used ((100*loonreq)/25) and it still output the correct result.

Comment: The (int) is just casting from the float to an int, this should be done, but isn't completely necessary. It's just so that the value going into the integer variables are actually integers themselves. If the compiler automatically converts the floats to integers without giving a type error then you are good.